# Wordpress white screen with word 'error'

Tags: errors

I am getting a white screen that just says 'error' on it.
I have removed all plugins, re-installed the theme and also re-installed wordpress. 
The website will work fine when going to the homepage, but as soon as I click on another page or category it returns this white screen.

Has anyone else seen this?

Comment: Have you enabled `WP_DEBUG`? If not, enable it, and report any **fatal error** messages generated. If you already have it enabled, check your server error logs, and report any **fatal error** messages there.

Comment: Can you post an URL?

Comment: Read [Debugging in WordPress](http://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress), then set `WP_DEBUG` and `WP_DEBUG_LOG` so that you can find out what the errors are.

Comment: I guess the error comes from the plugin "iThemes Security". You have to delete it and check the .htaccess if there is any code from the plugin.

Answer (score 1):

Could be a problem with your .htaccess. Check the permalink settings, change to something else and hit save. If there is an error, there's your problem.

It could also be with the theme. Try out another theme (such as the default) to see if any error appears.

Comment: It's not the theme or the .htaccess I have tried all of this. I've just discovered that the site will work fine in firefox, but as soon as I open it in chrome, it will give the error. And then I try opening in firefox agian and get the error. It's very odd

Comment: Browsers are unrelated to this problem until you are getting pages from browser cache.    Can you access the admin area?

Answer (score 1):

you may also check for whitespace at then end of functions.php file or more specifically white space above the opening  If you start over with all new installs the only possible issue would be on your machine, bug of some sort.

Answer (score 0):

Change the line in wp-config.php from

**define('WP_DEBUG', false);**

to

**define('WP_DEBUG', true);**

and see what information shows up.

Comment: This is a Comment, not an Answer. And as a matter of fact, it's the first Comment made to the Question 19 hours ago...

Comment: sorry, I am new to StackExchange ... how do you add a comment to new question?  I do not see an option to add a comment except after I've added an answer and someone commented.

Comment: Take a look at this: [faq#reputation]. As a matter of fact, you'll earn your first badge after reading all the FAQ ;)

Comment: thanks ... I'll go read that now ... didn't find that before

Comment: guess I am too new of a user to comment on existing questions that don't already have comments, I need like a 50 reputation, so sorry for posting it in an answer

Comment: No problem. Five upvotes on Answers are not hard to get. This will be helpful: [How to Answer](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/how-to-answer) and [How do I write a good answer to a question?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/7656/185667). Oh, by the way, welcome! :)